# Database of finite presentations of used groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, big-list, presentations-of-groups, online-resources

Do You know any **kind of database** of **presentations of groups**?

It may be on-line or off-line in form of tables, ideally case would be integrated in some Computer Algebra System. I am interested the most in infinite group presentations, but feel free to put here also information about tables of presentations of finite groups.

Maybe this thread should be wiki-type because probably there is many good answers to this question, and it is hard to compare for example software system with some kind of book or publication about this matter? I add biglist tag in a hope that it would appear;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[GAP](http://www.gap-system.org) has the following:

- [Finitely Presented Groups](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap47.html)
- [Presentations and Tietze Transformations](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap48.html)

An overview of all data libraries in GAP can be found [here](http://www.gap-system.org/Datalib/datalib.html).

The following was a comment, but should be part of the answer:

- There was a lovely book that listed lots of this sort of material 
  presentations, Group Tables by A. D. Thomas, G. V. Wood. It may not
  answer your question but if you can get your hands on a copy is
  an interesting  perspective.
  It was published in the Shiva Mathematics series.

Comment: You answer is OK, Thank You! This is what I am looking for, but maybe someone give us also another references, maybe on off-line tables?

Comment: There is on the GAP site the following:

ftp://ftp.gap-system.org/pub/gap/gap-3.4.4/deposit/gap/gpl.ps.gz

Comment: There was a lovely book that listed lots of this sort of material presentations,

Group Tables by A. D. Thomas, G. V. Wood. 

It may not answer your question but if you can get your hands on a copy is an interesting perspective. 

Comment: Definitely it is interesting, so Probably You should place it as an answer not a comment!

Comment: It's worth mentioning that one of the things that GAP bundles - as well as several other software packages - is the Small Groups Database; based on some enumeration of groups, it gives you a (size,index number) indexing to all finite groups of size at most some upper bound.

And this works perfectly fine offline.

Answer (score 6):

Related to your question, perhaps... there's the [Atlas of finite group representations](http://for.mat.bham.ac.uk/atlas/).  Although the atlas itself might not be what you're after, the above page contains links that might be more relevant.

Comment: This looks like a very useful site.

Comment:  As I know the site You post I agree that it is very useful. As I am asking about presentations, it may looks like it is not the answer. But it has also informations about presentations as well. So it is definitely in scope of the question, not only related! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In my dissertation I developed an algorithm for finding bounds on $H_2$ of a finitely presented group with finite field coefficients. I was motivated by a conjecture Quillen on the (co)homology of linear groups. As such, I included an appendix with presentations of several linear groups and the homology calculations using my algorithms. I didn't include the list of presentations for publication, but if these types of groups are of interest I could get it to you.

Comment: @Josh Perhaps you could say a bit more on your work.  Is it available as a paper implemented in some system /  package etc? This could be useful to others.