# Catalogue of groups with short finite presentations

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, computational-group-theory

For various types of groups, there exist catalogues of those groups of the
particular type which are "small" in a certain sense. — For example:

- The [GAP Small Groups Library](https://www.gap-system.org/Packages/smallgrp.html) catalogizes groups of small order,
- The [GAP Transitive Groups Library](https://www.gap-system.org/Packages/transgrp.html) and the [GAP Primitive Groups Library](https://www.gap-system.org/Packages/primgrp.html)
  catalogize transitive, respectively primitive, subgroups of symmetric groups
  of small degree,
- The [GAP Perfect Groups Library](https://www.gap-system.org/Datalib/perfect.html) catalogizes perfect groups
  of small order,

and so on.

**Question:** Does there exist such data library for groups with "short"
finite presentations?

*Remarks:*

- There is a [12-years-old question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15094/) asking for such database.
  At that time, apparently such database was not available.
  But maybe this has changed in the meantime(?)
- When setting the *length* of a finite presentation equal to
  the sum of the lengths of the relators, for every presentation on two
  generators of length at most $10$, it is straightforward to decide
  whether the corresponding group $G$ is trivial, nontrivial but finite,
  or infinite (if $G$ is infinite, this can be seen from the abelian
  invariants of $G$, $G'$ or $G''$, and if $G$ is finite, coset
  enumeration finishes even with very small limits). Where things start
  to get more interesting is length $11$. One of the few examples
  for which deciding finiteness seems more tricky is the group
  $$
  G \ := \ \langle a, b \ | \ a^3 = ab^{-3}a^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}b = 1 \rangle. 
    $$
  What is easy to see is that $G/G'' \cong {\rm C}_{37} \rtimes {\rm C}_9$,
  and that $G''$ is perfect — but beyond that, things seem to get more
  difficult. Almost for sure, people have considered this presentation
  (and other similar presentations) before. Looking into an appropriate
  data library would tell what is known about that (and other similar)
  groups immediately.

Comment: Giles Gardam’s thesis contains a useful census of all one-relator  groups with relator length less than 9 or so (up to Nielsen equivalence).

Comment: Marco Linton maintains a database of one-relator presentations here: https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/linton/homepage/ .

Comment: In writing such tables It would be useful to have rules so as to add $c(x,y)=xy^{-1}$ and $[x,y]=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ in the language and thus consider, say, $[x,[x,y]]$ as a very short relator (of length maybe 3 rather than 10).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would very much like to have such a database and would like to contribute to its development. Prompted by this question, we talked about what such a database could look like (e.g. in terms of groups covered, functionality etc.) at a discussion session of a workshop in Manchester with Ian Leary, Marco Linton, Saul Schleimer and Henry Wilton. I encourage anyone interested in this to contact me.

As some inspiration, I'll link this [mathoverflow question on atlas-like websites](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354327).